# Why marker-mid not working on line element in d3.js V4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js, svg

I want to show an arrow on the middle of one edge to show it's direction. Currently it can work on marker-start and marker-end. But can not work on marker-mid. I've checked the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/marker-mid) and it shows that it should be work. Could anyone help? Thanks so much!

Here is my code for my edge:

```
    SVG = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +SVG.attr("width"),
        height = +SVG.attr("height"),
        transform = d3.zoomIdentity;

    g = SVG.append("g");//a group for zoom in 
    const edge = g.selectAll(".g")//put the edge in a group
        .data(edges)
        .enter().append("g");

    edge.append("line")
        .attr("marker-mid","url(#c)")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(l) {
            var sourceNode = nodes.filter(function(d) {
                return d.id == l.outnode
            })[0];
            d3.select(this).attr("y1", sourceNode.y);
            return sourceNode.x
        })
        .attr("x2", function(l) {
            var targetNode = nodes.filter(function(d) {
                return d.id == l.innode
            })[0];
            d3.select(this).attr("y2", targetNode.y);
            return targetNode.x
        })
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "black");

    edge.append("text")
        .attr("class","linetext")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.description;
        })
        .attr("x", function(l) {
            var sourceNode = nodes.filter(function(d) {
                return d.id == l.outnode
            })[0];
            var targetNode = nodes.filter(function(d) {
                return d.id == l.innode
            })[0];
            d3.select(this).attr("y", (sourceNode.y+ targetNode.y)/2);
            return (sourceNode.x + targetNode.x)/2
        })
        .on("dblclick", editEdgeText);
```

for the style:

```
<svg id="myP" width="90%" height="500">
  <defs>
    <marker id="c" refX="12" refY="6" markerWidth="12" markerHeight="12" orient="auto" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="red">
      <circle cx="6" cy="6" r="5" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: The explanation is very simple: a line has no vertex.

Comment: A workaround is to use marker-start or end and displace the marker position to the middle of the line using dynamically set values of refX and refY

Comment: Hi Gerardo, I've tried to add a vertex on my line by doing this:
        edge.attr("d",function(l){
                midX = (targetNode.x - sourceNode.x) / 2 + sourceNode.x;
                midY = (targetNode.y - sourceNode.y) / 2 + sourceNode.y;
                return 'M' + sourceNode.x + ',' + sourceNode.y + 'L' + midX + ',' + midY + 'L' + targetNode.x + ',' + targetNode.y;
            })
But it still doesn't work. Actually I'm not sure is there any difference between add a vertex in line and path?

Comment: Hi Michael, trying on working with it. Thanks for your advice!